# Locating MySQL tables, they are not in datadir and the files cannot be found on disc

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with locating tables in mySQL. I know this question was asked milion times
e.g. [Location of database tables - MySQL - Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843381/location-of-database-tables-mysql-windows-xp)
but the answers do not seem to help. The tables are not in the dir given in my.ini. And there is also no file named as my database on disc. please help. thank you.

Comment: exact same issue here. The datadir only contains mysql and performance_schema but doesn't have my own databases. The databases are showing up in mysql command, phpmyadmin and working 100% with 3rd parties like wordpress, but the location is missing!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows you should to be careful, because sometimes there are more than one options file, so you have to be sure of which file the mysql server is loading, you can view that path running this query in any mysql client:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_variables 
WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'DATADIR';
```

Comment: Thank your for a fast response. Unfortunately it does not help, DATADIR points to a DIR in my.ini and there are no my tables. I even tried to remove MySQL and check what is left behind. No files with my tables. Reinstall and voila the database exists. And now I see other strange thing- I put a frm, myd a myi in  DATADIR/newdatabase and USE newdatabase gives unknown database.... Somehow MySQL is a mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

solved,

there's a folder `ProgramData` right under `Program Files` in the c: drive and this is acting as a sort of app data for some programs. So for me my datadir in mysql is saying:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data
```

but the actual location for any aditional databases I create is:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data
```

Hope this helps ;)