# why I can't see my database in ...\MySQL Server 5.6\data

Tags: mysql, database, file

I create two database and  tables in mysql ,but I can't see any data

file in "\MySQL Server 5.6\data" . In "\MySQL Server 5.6\data" just mysql file and

performance_schema. I really want to post images but it shows I don't have enough reputation.

ps. six  database: "imo","information_schema","performance_schema","test","world"

Comment: How are you trying to access the database?

Comment: I typed "mysql database location windows" into Google. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9414300/242520 http://stackoverflow.com/a/18465068/242520 or just look at the Google results

Comment: I use mysql to create database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical location of the database files can be found in the [`DATADIR` server system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir):

```
mysql> SELECT @@DATADIR;
+---------------------------------------------+
| @@DATADIR                                   |
+---------------------------------------------+
| C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Whatever you need that information for, please bear in mind that there's normally little use for manual file manipulation in daily operation:

- You can't read data from those files
- You can't make reliable backups by copying them